# Custom Swagger UI method parameter placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Is it possible to change the background placeholder text for method parameter such as `fromDate` (See picture) to something else lile `yyyy-MM-dd`?

[image]

So far I have tried to add following to my endpoints without achieving what I really would want.

```
.WithOpenApi(operation =>
{
    operation.Summary = "Summary text";
    var parameter = operation.Parameters[0];
    parameter.Example = new OpenApiString("example text");
    return operation;
});
```

Comment: If you replace `parameter.Example = ...` with `parameter.Extensions.Add("x-example", new OpenApiString("yyyy-MM-dd"));` does it work?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: Example seems to always override what there is and the goal was to replace the background/placeholder text.

Answer (score 1):

First you should add `SwaggerDefaultValues` operation filter

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the Swagger/Swashbuckle operation filter used to document the implicit API version parameter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>This <see cref="IOperationFilter"/> is only required due to bugs in the <see cref="SwaggerGenerator"/>.
    /// Once they are fixed and published, this class can be removed.</remarks>
    public class SwaggerDefaultValues : IOperationFilter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Applies the filter to the specified operation using the given context.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="operation">The operation to apply the filter to.</param>
        /// <param name="context">The current operation filter context.</param>
        public void Apply( OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context )
        {
            var apiDescription = context.ApiDescription;

            // REF: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1752#issue-663991077
            foreach ( var responseType in context.ApiDescription.SupportedResponseTypes )
            {
                // REF: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/b7cf75e7905050305b115dd96640ddd6e74c7ac9/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/SwaggerGenerator/SwaggerGenerator.cs#L383-L387
                var responseKey = responseType.IsDefaultResponse ? "default" : responseType.StatusCode.ToString();
                var response = operation.Responses[responseKey];

                foreach ( var contentType in response.Content.Keys )
                {
                    if ( !responseType.ApiResponseFormats.Any( x => x.MediaType == contentType ) )
                    {
                        response.Content.Remove( contentType );
                    }
                }
            }

            if ( operation.Parameters == null )
            {
                return;
            }

            // REF: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/412
            // REF: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/pull/413
            foreach ( var parameter in operation.Parameters )
            {
                var description = apiDescription.ParameterDescriptions.First( p => p.Name == parameter.Name );

                if ( parameter.Description == null )
                {
                    parameter.Description = description.ModelMetadata?.Description;
                }

                if ( parameter.Schema.Default == null && description.DefaultValue != null )
                {
                    // REF: https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/429#issuecomment-605402330
                    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize( description.DefaultValue, description.ModelMetadata.ModelType );
                    parameter.Schema.Default = OpenApiAnyFactory.CreateFromJson( json );
                }

                parameter.Required |= description.IsRequired;
            }
        }
    }
```

After that you should register it with Swagger

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    // add a custom operation filter which sets default values
    options.OperationFilter<SwaggerDefaultValues>();
    
    var fileName = typeof( Program ).Assembly.GetName().Name + ".xml";
    var filePath = Path.Combine( AppContext.BaseDirectory, fileName );

    // integrate xml comments
    options.IncludeXmlComments( filePath );
});
```

Please be sure to enable documentation file to be published, so edit corresponding csproj with this

```
 <PropertyGroup>
  
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

[Project on GitHub](https://github.com/Lonli-Lokli/SO_74453046)
With this setup this controller will look like this

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Example here is GetWithBodyMethodParameters
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id" example="5">One of IDs</param>
    /// <param name="text" example="something">Some text used to filter</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet("/with-body-method-parameters/{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetWithBodyMethodParameters(int id, [FromBody] string text) => Ok();
```

[image]

Comment: I'm more familiar with this way. Just wanted to try something else. :) Might use this way though.

Comment: Hi, when is the .xml file supposed to be generated ? I get an error because this file doesn't exist. I put the `SwaggerDefaultValues.cs` next to `Program.cs` with exactly your code, and the second block of code in my `Program.cs`, but I get an error at `options.IncludeXmlComments( filePath );` because this file doesn't exist. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Aooor I've added this info to the post

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli Thanks, I don't have any more errors at compile time, but it still doesn't work for the example. I tried to place the tag above the function in my controller, above the record or above the attribute in the record, in all cases it does not work.

Comment: I've added link to working sample on GitHub, please compare to your version